# Unstable Closed Loop System

Tags: matlab, controls, transfer

You are given a transfer function G(s)=1.81K(s+20)/(0.03338(s^3+10s^2+32s+32)). This system is connected with unity negative feedback . Determine the smallest positive value of K which makes the closed-loop system unstable. Give the answer to 3 d.p.

Correct Answer: 
0.531 ± 0.02

This question is set by my lecturer and I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: What have you tried? We need more information about what you aren't understanding in order to help you.

Comment: thanks for the help. but I figured it out on my own.

Comment: Perhaps you could post your answer? You are able to self-answer questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The closed loop system will become unstable as soon as the rlocus function is no longer in the LHP. Either of the two lines when they intersect with 0 on the x-axis. Assume K=1 at first as we are multiplying by the gain.

```
    >> G=tf([1.81 36.2],[0.03338 0.3338 1.0682 1.0682])

G =

                1.81 s + 36.2
  ------------------------------------------
  0.03338 s^3 + 0.3338 s^2 + 1.068 s + 1.068

Continuous-time transfer function.

>> rlocus(G)
```

you should see that when the real axis is 0 the gain is at 0.531.
if we want greater accuracy we can simply use the rlocfind(G,(point that it is 0)

Answer (score 0):

A smart friend of mine showed me that "Routh Array" is the key for this equation.

Expand the polynomial as you have it, therefore you will have this:

```
VARS        TERM            VALUE
A           s^3             0.03338
B           s^2             0.3338
C           s               1.06816 + 1.81Κ
D                           1.06816 + 36.2Κ
```

Equate them as `A*D=B*C` and you will have the term `"s^3"` on both sides and then you can cancel it out and solve for `K`.

```
(0.03338)(1.06816 + 36.2K) s^3  =   (0.3338)(1.06816 + 1.81K) s^3
0.0357 + 1.2084K        =       0.3566 + 0.6042K
(1.2084 - 0.6042) K     =       0.3566-0.0357
K   =   0.5311155247
```

Otherwise use the `rlocus` function in MATLAB.